# Why is WRF-Chem not reading my emissions data?

Tags: models, atmosphere-modelling, wrf, wrf-chem

I've been trying to run WRF-Chem with my emissions but they are not being read by WRF-Chem. RADM2.

I have emissions for the whole week, so `io_style_emissions = 2` and the emissions are in `wrfchem_d01_2014_08_04_00:00:00` format, just one emissions file. I thought `io_form_auxinput5 == 11`, but I have error I had to comment that line in `namelist.input`, and maybe that is the reason. I could model with 2 12-hours emissions files but that is not my goal, because I developed the emissions model, with high resolution temporal and spatial, and I would lose to much information otherwise.

The whole configuration for running WRF is [here](https://hackmd.io/s/B1hsu6qol).

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI, it's not in beta yet, but check out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107422/air-quality-modeling

Comment: Which inventory are you using?

Comment: I developed an emissions model as part of my PhD as an R package that I will upload soon. It has traffic and some industries

Answer (score 4):

I could run model, i just had to change a bit the namelist. I added three parameters:io_form_auxinput5 = 2,auxinput5_inname = 'wrfchemi_d$<domain>$_$<date>$'  and frames_per_auxinput5                = 168. (168 hours of emissions and hours of simulation)

```
&time_control
 run_days                            = 0,
 run_hours                           = 0,
 run_minutes                         = 0,
 run_seconds                         = 0,
 start_year                          = 2014,
 start_month                         = 08,
 start_day                           = 04,
 start_hour                          = 00,
 start_minute                        = 00,
 start_second                        = 00,
 end_year                            = 2014,
 end_month                           = 08,
 end_day                             = 11,
 end_hour                            = 00,
 end_minute                          = 00,
 end_second                          = 00,
 interval_seconds                    = 21600
 input_from_file                     = .true.,.true.,.true.,
 history_interval                    = 60,
 history_outname                     = "/scr4/sibarra/masp/run2/1km/wrfout_d<domain>_<date>"
 frames_per_outfile                  = 5000,
 restart                             = .false.,
 restart_interval                    = 10080,
 auxinput5_interval_m                = 60,   
 io_form_auxinput2                   = 2,
 io_form_auxinput5                   = 2,
 auxinput5_inname                    = 'wrfchemi_d<domain>_<date>'
 frames_per_auxinput5                = 168,
 io_form_history                     = 2
 io_form_restart                     = 2
 io_form_input                       = 2
 io_form_boundary                    = 2
 debug_level                         = 100
 /

 &domains
 time_step                           = 6,
 time_step_fract_num                 = 0,
 time_step_fract_den                 = 1,
 max_dom                             = 1,
 e_we                                = 191,
 e_sn                                = 181,
 e_vert                              = 35,
 p_top_requested                     = 5000,
 num_metgrid_levels                  = 27,
 vert_refine_fact                    = 1,
 num_metgrid_soil_levels             = 4,
 dx                                  = 1000,
 dy                                  = 1000,
 grid_id                             = 3,
 parent_id                           = 2,
 i_parent_start                      = 57,
 j_parent_start                      = 59,
 parent_grid_ratio                   = 5,
 parent_time_step_ratio              = 5,
 feedback                            = 1,
 smooth_option                       = 0
 /

 &physics
 mp_physics                          = 2,
 ra_lw_physics                       = 1,
 ra_sw_physics                       = 2,
 radt                                = 15,
 sf_sfclay_physics                   = 1,
 sf_surface_physics                  = 2,
 bl_pbl_physics                      = 1,
 bldt                                = 0,
 cu_physics                          = 0,
 cudt                                = 0,
 cu_diag                             = 1,
 cu_rad_feedback                     = .true.,
 isfflx                              = 1,
 ifsnow                              = 0,
 icloud                              = 0,
 surface_input_source                = 1,
 num_soil_layers                     = 4,
 num_land_cat                        = 20,
 sf_urban_physics                    = 1,
 /

 &fdda
 /

 &dynamics
 w_damping                           = 0,
 diff_opt                            = 1,
 km_opt                              = 4,
 diff_6th_opt                        = 0,
 diff_6th_factor                     = 0.12,
 base_temp                           = 290.
 damp_opt                            = 0,
 zdamp                               = 5000.,
 dampcoef                            = 0.2
 khdif                               = 0,
 kvdif                               = 0,
 non_hydrostatic                     = .true., .true., .true.,
 moist_adv_opt                       = 1,     
 scalar_adv_opt                      = 1,     
 /

 &bdy_control
 spec_bdy_width                      = 5,
 spec_zone                           = 1,
 relax_zone                          = 4,
 specified                           = .true., .false.,.false.,
 nested                              = .false., .true., .true.,
 /

 &grib2
 /

 &chem
 kemit                               = 1,
 chem_opt                            = 1,
 bioemdt                             = 15,
 photdt                              = 15,
 chemdt                              = 2.,
 io_style_emissions                  = 2,
 emiss_inpt_opt                      = 1,
 emiss_opt                           = 2,
 chem_in_opt                         = 1,
 phot_opt                            = 2,
 gas_drydep_opt                      = 1,
 aer_drydep_opt                      = 0,
 bio_emiss_opt                       = 0,
 dust_opt                            = 0,
 dmsemis_opt                         = 0,
 seas_opt                            = 0,
 gas_bc_opt                          = 1,
 gas_ic_opt                          = 1,
 aer_bc_opt                          = 1,
 aer_ic_opt                          = 1,
 aer_op_opt                          = 0,
! opt_pars_out                       = 0,
 gaschem_onoff                       = 1,
 aerchem_onoff                       = 1,
 wetscav_onoff                       = 0,
 cldchem_onoff                       = 0,
 vertmix_onoff                       = 1,
 chem_conv_tr                        = 0,
 biomass_burn_opt                    = 0,
 aer_ra_feedback                     = 0
 have_bcs_chem                       = .false., .false., .false.,
 /

 &namelist_quilt
 nio_tasks_per_group = 0,
 nio_groups = 1,
/
```

Comment: I have 3 netcdf files in which has been interpolated into my wrf-grid. but how can I write all 3 files in a file to be readable for wrf-chem??in matlab or in R? thank you so much

Comment: Using R do install.packages("eixport"), then library(export). You first need to create your wrfchemi file. in R read the netcf with library ncdf4 and put your NC data in your wrfchemi export function wrf_put. Read the reference manual here https://atmoschem.github.io/eixport/